# HTTP 401 Error while posting XML to REST

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, authentication, rest

I am trying to post a XML to REST Service. Here's the code I am using:

I am getting following error, while calling the service.

**The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.**

I have also tried setting NetworkCredentials directly i.e.

```
NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
serviceRequest.Credentials = nc;
```

Thanks for your help.

```
Uri address = new Uri("https://localhost:30000/restservice/");

// Create the web request  
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;

// Set type to POST  
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";

string data = @"<Sample XML Here>";

// Create a byte array of the data we want to send  
byte[] byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

// Set the content length in the request headers  
request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;

// Write data  
using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
}

string usernamePassword = username + ":" + password;

CredentialCache mycache = new CredentialCache();

mycache.Add(address, "Basic", new NetworkCredential(username, password));
request.Credentials = mycache;

// Get response  
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    // Get the response stream  
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

    // Console application output  
    Response.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Fiddler and look in the WWW-Authenticate header that is returned from the server.  That will tell you what kind of authentication scheme the server supports.

Comment: Thanks Darrel. Here is what I am getting from fiddler: No Proxy-Authenticate Header is present. No WWW-Authenticate Header is present.

Comment: Wow that sucks.  The HTTP spec says a 401 should always be accompanied by a WWW-Authenticate header.  What's the tech of your server?

Comment: I am working on Windows Server 2008 R2. Here's the article I referred, which finally worked http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx. Still have same issues with using WebClient and the sample above.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to try:

- Change the content type as you're not posting json to it
- Not encode the data as its expecting xml, not a binary stream

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Changed ContentType to "application/xml", still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

try set Credentials in request like this

```
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
```